# ML-Flow installation in R

Tags: r, ubuntu, mlflow

I have installed MLFLOW for R in my ubuntu environment. When I try to execute any command for mlflow I am getting below error

> mlflow_ui()
>   Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), stdin,  :
>     cannot start processx process (system error 2, No such file or directory) @unix/processx.c:573

Comment: Similar problem with the error: Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), stdin,  : 
  Command not found @win/processx.c:977 ----- Did you solve it?

Comment: @digvijay I'm having the same error message in Windows, had anyone solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can install MLFlow separately using `pip` and then specify the variables in your `~/.Renviron`. If you don't have a `.Renviron` file, create one. (Checkout out `help("Startup")` in R for more info).

The environment variables you need to set in the `.Renviron` file are:

`MLFLOW_PYTHON_BIN` and `MLFLOW_BIN`. These need to set to the location of your python executable and mlflow executable.

Simply get those by running `which python` and `which mlflow` after installing `mlflow` with pip.

Make sure to restart Rstudio (perhaps try removing mlflow and re-installing the package).

Then there will be no need to run `mlflow::install_mlflow()`.

Answer (score 0):

@digvijay have you [installed conda](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/R-api.html#install-mlflow) & invoked the R [`install_mlflow` function](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/R-api.html#install-mlflow) on your machine?  It's necessary to do so before invoking the R APIs - `install_mlflow` creates a conda environment for installing the MLflow CLI, which some of the R APIs (e.g. `mlflow_ui`) depend on.

Comment: Yes I did that. Post installation mlflow , below are commands that I executed                        library(mlflow)                                                                                                                  install_mlflow()

Comment: I had a similar problem, then I realized that the python version shipped with reticulate was 3.7 and install_mlflow() would by default install for 3.6, so I tried mlflow::install_mlflow("3.7") and it worked.